# I would like to know if this is possible in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I was wondering if it is possible to display "Enter the number of wins on monday, tuesday, wednesday, and so on" sequentialy after each input. The only method I can think of is to make multiple inputs in the module.

```
def getWins():
counter = 1
totalWins = 0
dailyWins = 0
while counter <= 7:
    dailyWins = raw_input('Enter the number of wins acquired for each day this week:')
    totalWins = totalWins + dailyWins
    counter = counter + 1
return totalWins
```

Comment: You can also have the input be a list and parse it accordingly.

What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and sorry for not elaborating, what I was looking for was for the program to list a different day of the week after each user input, so the user can input data for the different days of the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def getWins():
    week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    scores = {} # Perhaps you want to return a dictionary? If not, just set this to 0 and += score below. Also, remove sum()
    for day in week:
        score = int(raw_input("Enter the number of wins on {}: ".format(day)))
        scores[day] = score
    return sum(scores.values())

getWins()
"""
>>> getWins()
Enter the number of wins on Monday: 5
Enter the number of wins on Tuesday: 4
Enter the number of wins on Wednesday: 5
Enter the number of wins on Thursday: 1
Enter the number of wins on Friday: 3
Enter the number of wins on Saturday: 7
Enter the number of wins on Sunday: 9
34
"""
```

Comment: Thanks goodies this is exactly what I was looking for, I am trying to create a data tracking program for my intro to programing class

Answer (score 0):

> The only method I can think of is to make multiple inputs in the module

- In Python 2.7, `raw_input` returns a string
- Strings can be split

You could let the user enter the values for the whole week in one `raw_input`, separated by spaces, comma, etc.

```py
def get_wins():
    data = raw_input('Enter the number of wins for each day, separated by spaces: ')

    wins = [int(win) for win in data.split() if win.isdigit()]
    return sum(wins)
```

Comment: Yea but could I get a total value at the end if the user puts all the values in 1 input ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to create a list of all the inputs made by user as:

```
dailywins = map(int, raw_input("enter the daily wins of whole week").split()) 
# THIS gives you a list object of ints which can be manipulated any way you want(here input is space separated)
```

Now you can simply do:

```
totalwins = sum(dailywins)
```

to get `totalwins`